# Weaviate returns error when using nearText

Tags: weaviate

Giving Weaviate a go  using python client with the example for wine reviews, not sure if this is a function error:

**Query**:

```
query_result = ( client.query
    .get("Wine",["title","description"])
    .with_limit(5)
    .with_near_text({"concepts" : ["white"]})
    .do())
```

**Response**:

```
{'errors': [{'locations': [{'column': 20, 'line': 1}], 'message': 'Unknown argument "nearText" on field "Wine" of type "GetObjectsObj". Did you mean "nearVector" or "nearObject"?', 'path': None}]}
```

An empty query do return results as expected.

**Schema**:

```
{
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "Wine",
            "invertedIndexConfig": {
                "bm25": {
                    "b": 0.75,
                    "k1": 1.2
                },
                "cleanupIntervalSeconds": 60,
                "stopwords": {
                    "additions": null,
                    "preset": "en",
                    "removals": null
                }
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "name": "title",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "name": "description",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                }
            ],
            "replicationConfig": {
                "factor": 1
            },
            "shardingConfig": {
                "virtualPerPhysical": 128,
                "desiredCount": 1,
                "actualCount": 1,
                "desiredVirtualCount": 128,
                "actualVirtualCount": 128,
                "key": "_id",
                "strategy": "hash",
                "function": "murmur3"
            },
            "vectorIndexConfig": {
                "skip": false,
                "cleanupIntervalSeconds": 300,
                "maxConnections": 64,
                "efConstruction": 128,
                "ef": -1,
                "dynamicEfMin": 100,
                "dynamicEfMax": 500,
                "dynamicEfFactor": 8,
                "vectorCacheMaxObjects": 1000000000000,
                "flatSearchCutoff": 40000,
                "distance": "cosine"
            },
            "vectorIndexType": "hnsw",
            "vectorizer": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Weaviate should return the results "wine reviews" related to "white"

Answer (score 1):

I realised there was no vectorization by default, I solved the error by adding the model. The results are inaccurate though, don't yield the right results even if including exact keywords.

```
class_obj = {
    "class": "Wine",
    "vectorizer": "text2vec-transformers",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "title",
            "dataType": ["text"]
        },
        {
            "name": "description",
            "dataType": ["text"]
        }
    ],
    "moduleConfig": {
        "text2vec-transformers": {
            "vectorizeClassName": True
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We first have to understand, what `nearText` does actually. It queries(searches for) the nearest entries in the database, to the text(s) you provided with `nearText`.vectorize your entries.

In your provided schema, you used

```
{
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "Wine",
            "vectorizer": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Explicitly mentioning `No Vectorizer`. Thus, not finding any vectorizer and throwing an error.

You needed to add some vectorizer like `text2vec-openai` as well as make the `vectorizeClassName` to *True*.

```
class_obj = {
    "class": "Wine",
    "vectorizer": "text2vec-openai",
    "moduleConfig": {
        "text2vec-openai": {
            "vectorizeClassName": True
        }
    }  # Or "text2vec-cohere" or "text2vec-huggingface"
}
```

This works for me. Hope works for you to!

Comment: can this be done with your own vectorizer, not one of Weaviate's modules?